# Proper Way of Formatting Where Clause with Alias - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, alias

I'm stuck on an issue that I'm not quite sure how to properly reformat. Below are the relevant portions of a controller function:

```
$paidQuery = DB::table('shipments')
            ->leftJoin('customers', 'shipments.bill_to', '=', 'customers.id')
            ->leftJoin('customer_addresses', 'shipments.billerLocation', '=', 'customer_addresses.id')
            ->leftJoin('payments_distributions','shipments.id','=','payments_distributions.shipment_id')
            ->select('shipments.*', 'customers.customer_name','customer_addresses.billingMethod',DB::raw('COALESCE(sum(payments_distributions.amount),0) AS paid')); 
        $paidQuery->where('shipments.shipment_origin', 1);
        $paidQuery->where('shipments.balance', '<', 'paid')
                          ->where('shipments.balance','>', 0)
                          ->whereNotIn('shipments.shipment_billing_status', [2,3,5]);
        if(!empty($_GET['startDate']) || !empty($_GET['endDate'])){
            $paidQuery->where(function($query) {
                if(empty($_GET['startDate'])){
                    $startDate = Carbon::create(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    $startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
                }

                if(empty($_GET['endDate'])){
                    $endDate = Carbon::now();
                } else {
                    $endDate = $_GET['endDate'];
                }

                return $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                    ->orWhereNull('date');

            });
        }

        $paidQuery->whereNull('shipments.deleted_at')
        ->orderBy('shipments.pro_number', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('shipments.id')
        ->limit(100);
```

Now, as you can see above, there is a select statement (5th line), where at the end is an alias. This is there solely as an example of how the data that I get is returned. I've used it to verify what is and isn't working and that specific line works, the part that doesn't work is this line:

```
$paidQuery->where('shipments.balance', '<', 'paid')
```

What would be the proper way to get the sum (or zero (0)) of all of the `amount` from the `payments_distributions` table where the record IDs are the same?

I have been looking around and can't find an appropriate example what I am looking for, but am certain it is more likely the search terms or phrasing. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible in MySQL to use an alias defined in a select clause in a where clause, at the same level.  But, MySQL overloaded the `HAVING` operator to allow aliases to be used, so the following should work here:

```
$paidQuery = DB::table('shipments')
        ->leftJoin('customers', 'shipments.bill_to', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->leftJoin('customer_addresses', 'shipments.billerLocation', '=', 'customer_addresses.id')
        ->leftJoin('payments_distributions','shipments.id','=','payments_distributions.shipment_id')
        ->select('shipments.*', 'customers.customer_name','customer_addresses.billingMethod',DB::raw('COALESCE(sum(payments_distributions.amount),0) AS paid')); 
    $paidQuery->where('shipments.shipment_origin', 1);
    $paidQuery->having('shipments.balance', '<', 'paid');
    $paidQuery->where('shipments.balance', '>', 0)
    $paidQuery->whereNotIn('shipments.shipment_billing_status', [2,3,5]);
```

To be clear here, I am suggesting that you use the following raw MySQL:

```
HAVING paid > shipments.balance
```